# Common Lisp sort function removing an element from the original list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am using **SBCL** and when I use the `sort` function as follows,

```
CL-USER> (defparameter y '(5 7 2 9 4 6))
Y
CL-USER> y
(5 7 2 9 4 6)
CL-USER> (sort y #'>)
(9 7 6 5 4 2)
CL-USER> y
(7 6 5 4 2)
```

The biggest element (in this case 9) is removed from the original list.

Wondering what's happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sort`, according to the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sort_.htm#sort),

> destructively sort sequences according to the order determined by the predicate function.

In other words, it can modify its argument, and you should get the value returned as the result of the sorting operation.

```
CL-USER> (defvar y (list 5 7 2 9 4 6))
Y
CL-USER> (setf y (sort y #'>))
(9 7 6 5 4 2)
CL-USER> y
(9 7 6 5 4 2)
```

Note that, since it can modify its argument, it should be called with `copy-list` if we want to avoid such modification:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter y '(5 7 2 9 4 6))
Y
CL-USER> (sort (copy-list y) #'<)
(2 4 5 6 7 9)
CL-USER> y
(5 7 2 9 4 6)
```

Finally, note that modifying a literal value, like `'(5 7 2 9 4 6)`, can produce undefined behaviour, and should be avoided.

Comment: I think, your final answer is happening here.  Unpredictable answer.  But I tried many times, and every time the biggest element is removed. I can understand that it is destructive, but cannot understand the removal of element.

Comment: Destructive means that the original list ca  be altered, for instance by removing elements from the list or reordering them. SBCL is open source, so you could look at the code of sort.

Comment: I went through the code.  Very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 5):

```
(defvar *y* '(1 2 3))
```

So `*y*` points to `(1 2 3)`. Like this.

```
 *y*--->[*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]---> NIL
          |        |        |
          v        v        v
          1        2        3
```

Now if you evaluate `(sort *y* #'>`), then `*y*` gets evaluated first and the content gets passed to `sort`. Not the variable, the content! Inside the function `sort`, there is no reference to `*y*` available. What `sort` gets is a reference to the first cons cell.

Now when `sort` moves the `3` to the front, it can do that by putting a new cons cell to the front (that's one way to implement sorting). But `sort` can never update `*y*` to reference a different object, since it hasn't got a reference to `*y*` itself, but a reference to the first cons cell of `(1 2 3)`.

So, `sort` returns a sorted list and one is supposed to use that as a result, instead of using references which point to the original argument. The original argument list may have been altered:

`sort` is also possibly **destructive**.

**Note: the exact behavior of destructive sort is unspecified in Common Lisp**

Thus implementations may show different side effects. See for example the `CLISP` implementation:

```
[1]> (defvar *y* '(1 2 3))
*Y*
[2]> (sort *y* #'>)
(3 2 1)
[3]> *y*
(3 2 1)
```

Comment: But **sort** is not altering the original **string** or **vector**.

Comment: @SreekumarR : a) your example sorts a list, not a string or vector b) yes, `sort` can alter the original datastructure. The basic `sort` function in Common Lisp is destructive.